# SDWebImage button background image resize

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I have a button with a background Image that I download with `SDWebImage`. I want to keep the height constant and change the width by maintaining the aspect ratio and not cutting the image. Just constant height and dynamic width. What is wrong here?

```
//CODE FROM FUNCTION ---
button.sd_setBackgroundImage(with: url, for: .normal, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "img"),options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.resizeImage(image: image!, newHeight: 100), height: 100))
        button.frame = view.frame
    })
view.addSubview(button)
return view
```

This is my helper function

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newHeight: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    let scale = newHeight / image.size.height
    let newWidth = image.size.width * scale
    return newWidth
}
```

Comment: What is the output you're seeing, add the screenshot?

Comment: It gives me an error right now, so im completely on the wrong path here
`reason: 'layer <CALayer: 0x60800023cfe0> is a part of cycle in its layer tree`

Answer (score 0):

You can create **IBoutlet NSLayoutConstraint** for button width and give constant value for button width at run time as per image width (After downloading image).

Comment: I tried it like you said. Now I think I have 2 constraints of the same type and it deletes the new one. How can I replace my width constraint with the new one?